# how to set a label in Gnuplot next to line but include colour of line

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to put individual keys of lines next to each line, in gnuplot. I thought I could do this my setting label. However, I cannot get the colour and type of line to come up. This is what im trying:

```
key label "C=#FFC000" at graph 0.015,0.955
```

I want this to read C=(aline which is of colour #FFC000)

Thanks,

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but: Why would you want to do this? If you are putting the label next to the line, there is no need to indicate what the line looks like anymore. On the other hand, if you use a regular key, i.e., an identifying name with a line, there is no need to put it next to the line anymore. Also, with what you are intending to do, you might confuse the reader with the line segments appering everywhere.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I would not dictate others how to present their data. If you draw a large number of curves with short titles (i.e. just a number), placing labels near the curves may be better than a key - especially if line styles are repeated.

Comment: @sweber: I do not want to dictate; I just want the asker to think about whether they really want what they are asking for. Often, if things are not possible in a software like Gnuplot, there is a good reason for this. Also, I do not think that putting labels near the curves is a bad idea. I just think that putting labels near the curve *and* equipping them with keys is a bad idea.

Comment: Version 5 offers a possibility to add the title as label at the beginning or end of a line, although its use is quite limited (e.g. you must have to care yourself to increase the margins), `plot 'data.dat' using 1:2 title 'mytitle' at end`.

Comment: @ Wrzlprmft: ok, 'dictate' was a bit harsh. It is true that one should always think about how to present the data the best way.  On the other side, people on the web often answer "Why do you want to do that/You don't want to do that". Sometimes, it's justified, but often I think people know best what they want. Maybe, there's also a reason for a text _plus_ line sample, though I think it sounds odd, too.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do this, you will have to do it by hand, and you have to set text label and a piece of line separately:

```
set angle degrees

set label "Label" at 1,1 right
set arrow from 1,1 to 1.1, 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#FF0000" nohead

set label "Twwwwoooooooooo" at 1,2 right
set arrow from 1,2 to 1.1, 2 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#00FF00" nohead

set label "WithOffset" at 2,2 right offset -1, 0
set arrow from 2,2 to 2.1, 2 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#0000FF" nohead

set label "Rotated" at 2,1 right rotate by 45
set arrow from 2,1 to 2+0.1*cos(45), 1+0.1*sin(45) linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#FFC000" nohead
```

The `right` makes the text label right-flushed and the `offset -1, 0` causes the text to be shifted by 1 character width to the left. (This is more convenient than dealing with coordinates)

The last label/arrow demonstrates that you can also rotate the label. But while the text is simply rotated by 45°, the line is drawn between two points. So, unless the ratio of x/y units is not 1 (`set size ratio -1`), the line will not be displayed in a 45° angle, or you have to put in some more math.

Here is a result:

[image]